# How to properly use POST in an API request for Earth Explorer

Tags: python, api, post, python-requests

So first of all thanks, I'm really new to python and I am trying to understand APIs, I'm currently trying to log in into `/inventory/json/v/1.4.1/<request_code>?jsonRequest=<json_request_content>` which is the Earth Explorer API, and the first step is to Login, and according to the documentation I am supposed to use POST instead of GET, so here is what I got so far, and it works but this is what I

```py
import requests

import requests
user = 'xxxxx'
psword = 'xxxxx'

input_data= {'username':user,'password':psword,'catalogId':'EE'}
test=requests.post('https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/inventory/json/v/1.4.0/login?jsonRequest=input_data)')

print(test.text)
print(test.status_code)
```

```json
{
    "errorCode": "AUTH_ERROR",
    "error": "Passing credentials via URL is not permitted - use a POST request",
    "data": null,
    "api_version": "",
    "access_level": "guest",
    "executionTime": 0
}
200
```

I have no idea what to do, thank you so much. This is the documentation for the earth explorer API, thank you so much https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/inventory/documentation/json-api?version=1.4.1#login

Comment: that link is behind an authorization wall, which we can not see. maybe you have to use the auth patterns in the `requests` library

Comment: i´m sorry can you elaborate?

Comment: https://2.python-requests.org/en/v1.1.0/user/authentication/ and the link to the API docs requires a log-in, which we don't have

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I've been stuck on the same problem for hours...

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem while working with Earth Explorer API and managed to solve it by reading [usgs package code](https://github.com/kapadia/usgs/blob/master/usgs/api.py#L178). Basically, the problem is that you must send the request body as a string. That is, your request body must look like this when printed

```
{
    "jsonRequest": "{\"username\": \"???\", \"password\": \"???\", \"catalogId\": \"???\"}"
}
```

You can achieve this using

```py
import json
import requests

req_params = {
    'username': '???',
    'password': '???',
    'catalogId': '???',
}
req_txt = json.dumps(req_params)
req_body = {
    'jsonRequest': req_txt,
}

resp = requests.post('<LOGIN URL HERE>', req_body)
```

This code is actually taken from [usgs package](https://pypi.org/project/usgs/) I mentioned, so you should refer to it if you have any additional questions.